# Pure CSS Responsive Menu overflow-x issue and more

Tags: css

In this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZvBNW) I have 2 issues:

Hovering Category87 (sub Category81) the sub-submenu is not visible since it scroll right: I'm sure I have to add

`overflow-x: -100%`

but I've not found where to add it

Moreover there are issues on

> Category4

(and all the subcategories in the first column) that do not have the same behaviour as
Category27 and other, but on this point I have no idea of the bug.

Can pls suggest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your HTML code is invalid and may give you some errors. Note that categories that have subcategories like 4,7,13,19,27... aren't closed properly. By the way, I suggest you to indent the code and you will see it clearer.

   ```
   <li>
      <a href='/?cat_13'>Category 13</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='/?cat_14'>Category 14</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   ```
2. At line 343 you should remove `:not( :first-child )` in order to solve first column issues.

   ```
   .nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul li ul li {
     left: 100%;
     top:-1.5em;
   }
   ```
3. You should decide what to do with the last column. I don't know exactly what you mean by `overflow-x:-100%`. You might want the last column subcategories to go to the left to avoid window scrollbars. One option could be this:

   ```
   .nav li:last-child:hover ul li ul li {
     left: -100%;
     top:-1.5em;
   }
   ```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answers, I'll try immediately
Concerning HTML code invalid, yes probably: menu is much longer (some 270 submenues and valid, but too long for codepen and I cut it badly.
Concerning indention.. it is dynamically generated..

Comment: concerning point 2 it is OK
concerning point 3, if you hover on category 87 it seems nothing happen, but if you check horizontal scrollbar you see that the subcategory is displayed on the left.
I want to avoid horizontal scrolling, therefore when happens to scroll, I want to show the submenu to open on the left instead of right.

Comment: Joe, my last piece of code works. It gets the submenu to the left.